# Using and reusing Phaser instead of join()

Tags: java, multithreading, join, synchronization, phaser

I have to wait in main thread for termination of working threads, then (on some event) I start those threads and wait for termination again, etc.

Calling `join()` works well, but I want to do it faster.

Phaser looks like what I'm searching for, but I'm doing something wrong:

```
//*** application start ***
//create "empty" Phaser

//*** main thread ***
//event occured - start working threads
phaser.register();
//start working threads...
phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance(); //add arriveAndDeregister()?

// *** working thread start ***
phaser.register();
// do sth ...
// *** working thread end ***
phaser.arrive(); // replace with arriveAndDeregister()?
```

Comment: Why do you believe that using phasers (which has more intricate semantics) will be faster than doing `join()`? Fork/join instead is optimized for this pattern of branching short-lived workers and waiting for their termination; phasers are intended for long-running tasks that synchronize step-wise.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are **cannot** call `phaser.register()` from within the task being registered. When using phasers always follow these two rules:

1. **Only registered tasks can register other tasks.** This means that a task cannot register itself.
2. **All registered tasks must deregister before ending.** A good practice is to wrap the code using a phaser around a `finally` block that deregisters at the end (see example).

Here is how you would change your original example:

```
//*** application start ***
//create "empty" Phaser
final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);
//*** main thread ***
//event occurred - start working threads
for (int i = 0; i < WORKERS; i++) { // spawn some workers
  phaser.register(); // register the worker thread before starting it
  Thread worker = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
      public void run() {
        try { // wrap the worker's code with a finally, so you are sure the task will deregister from the phaser.
          // Worker's code
          // ...
          // *** working thread end ***
          // last operation is:
        } finally { // Very important to wrap
          phaser.arriveAndDeregister();
        }
      }
  });
  worker.start();
}
// wait for working threads...
phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();

// repeat pattern above: phaser.register() + worker.start()
phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();

// since the main task is done it deregisters itself from the phaser
phaser.arriveAndDeregister();
```

Comment: Why the task cannot register itself?

Comment: If a threads registers itself, then other threads may synchronize together *without* waiting for the thread registering itself, which defeats the purpose of having a barrier.